# How do I copy cells value when the description cell has a specific word in cell

Tags: excel, macos

Hi Guys I found this formula on another page?

=IF(Bravo!D3="Old", Bravo!A3,"Default")

This is great, but what if there is other text in that cell too? It will only copy if cell has "old" only in cell.
 For example if the cell contained "OLD" i would want it to be copied, but if it contained "OLD PLAN" I would also want this to be copied. how do I allow for this?

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that when someone types 'old' anywhere in that cell, so it could be "old plan" "old mobile" "bundle old" etc "old (anything)" that it would copy the value in another colum "Old Values" which will be hidden but used for other workings.

[Click for a pic to try and aid in my description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYqxQ.png)

Please remove if not allowed.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Should mention to work in my sheet I changed the above formula to =IF(C31="old", D31,"Default") as I am not working on multiple sheets

Comment: just for your pic, I suggest for the grey TOTAL: `=SUMIF(C31:C38,"<>old*",D31:D38)` this will automatically sum up all values which description does not start with "old". Also case does not matter so OLD and old or Old will all not be summed up. or for you formula to be not case sensitive: `=IF(LOWER(LEFT(C31,3))="old", D31,"Default")` or `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("old",C31)=1,D31,NA()),"Default")`... still there are lots of ways to approach that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compare first 3 chars, e.g. with function left:

```
=IF(left(Bravo!D3,3)="Old", Bravo!A3,"Default")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment J. So for my actual spreadsheet it would be =IF(left(C31,3="old", D31,"Default")    ? I get an error of too many arguments. Sorry should mention I am a bit of a novice. thanks for your help.

Comment: Whoops I was missing a little ')' thanks for that... that will work great if I can make sure the guys using the sheet put "OLD" in first... do you know if there is a way to search the cell for "old" anywhere within the cell? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, there is the function "find" that should help, then compare the result is >0.

Comment: Thanks again... Now have the issue of trying to total up just the values that now don't have 'old' in the descriptive text. Do you know how I would go about achieving this?

Comment: Not to worry... I'll just minus the total of the old column.. Thanks for all your help... you have dramatically eased my headache